# Java Desktop com banco de Mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Estou tentando gravar uma imagem no banco de dados MySql, a tabela está logo abaixo, o código pra carregar a imagem está logo em seguida, estou usando um botão pra carregar em um JLabel, após isso, uso outro botão pra inserir a imagem no banco, logo abaixo está o código do insert, enfim não estou conseguindo gravar no banco de dados.

Banco Mysql

```
create table imagens(
id int not null auto_increment,
cpf varchar(15) not null,
foto blob null,
primary key (id),
foreign key (cpf)
references funcionario(cpf)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Aqui e a onde eu carrego a imagem no JLabel a partir de um JFileChooser

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();   //Cria o objeto do tipo Janela JFileChooser
        fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Escolha a Foto");  //Define o título do JFileChooser
        fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);  //Define que só serão abertos arquivos
        {
            if (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                try {
                    File arquivo = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();//arquivo
                    BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(arquivo); //carrega a imagem real num buffer
                    BufferedImage aux = new BufferedImage(100, 80, bi.getType());//cria um buffer auxiliar com o tamanho desejado
                    Graphics2D g = aux.createGraphics();//pega a classe graphics do aux para edicao
                    AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance((double) 100 / bi.getWidth(), (double) 80 / bi.getHeight());//cria a transformacao
                    g.drawRenderedImage(bi, at);//pinta e transforma a imagem real no auxiliar
                    foto.setIcon(new ImageIcon(aux));//seta no jlabel
                    foto.setText(null);

                   // ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    //Jogue a imagem lá dentro do byteArrayOutputStream
                    //ImageIO.write(aux, "png", byteArrayOutputStream);

                }catch (IOException ex) {

                }


            }
    }
```

Este e meu insert.

```
String prep = "INSERT INTO imagens (foto,cpf)  VALUES(?,?)";

Image image = ((ImageIcon)foto.getIcon()).getImage();
PreparedStatement sttmt = con.prepareStatement(prep);
JTextField cpff = cpf;

sttmt.setBytes(1, bytes(image));
sttmt.setString(2, cpf.getText());

sttmt.execute();
sttmt.close();
```

Comment: Qual a mensagem de erro?

Comment: Ae e que ta não mostrar erro nenhum,simplesmente não inseri.

Comment: Você pode logar ou 'cuspir' essa exception para algum lugar, facilita o caminho para resolução do problema "catch (IOException ex) { faça algo aqui }"

Comment: @GleistonJosedeSantana troque `catch (IOException ex) { }` por `catch (IOException ex) { e.printStackTrace();}` e posta o erro disparado, agora nao sei pq vc fez um catch Exception se nao ta pedindo pra mostrar o erro disparado.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, não é recomendável você colocar uma imagem direto no banco de dados. pois além de ser desnecessário iria ocupar muito espaço e fazer seu banco inflar de uma maneira exorbitante.

Tente upar essa imagem em algum lugar, como uma pasta compartilhada na rede ou em um serviço de nuvem. e no banco de dados tu só salva o caminho relativo da imagem por exemplo:

```
\\servidor\app\imagens\usuario\perfil.png
ou
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zerossB/TotalRam/master/Images/TotalRAM-screen.png
```

Ai para recuperar tu passa como o caminho da imagem:

```
ImageIcon logo = new ImageIcon(new URL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zerossB/TotalRam/master/Images/TotalRAM-screen.png"));
```

Assim seu banco ficara mais leve e com menos processamento de dados entre a app e o banco.

Comment: Gostei da ideia da pasta compartilhada na rede,não tinha pensado por este lado,coisas de iniciante,bom gente muito obrigado,vou fazer a implementação,muito obrigado mesmo pelas dicas,valeu...

Comment: Precisar só chamar ;D